How to increase blur power as the video plays with FFmpeg?
I'm trying to increase blur power throughout entire video. My code is like this but it seems that FFmpeg don't recognise t:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]smartblur=t*2" output.mp4

I remember using t in overlay but I don't know why it doesn't work here.
I also tried boxblur and gblur but it didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no option to render a blur over time. The workaround is to apply a blur to one instance of the input and overlay and fade in over time. Here is a fade out example which can be adapted to fade in.

Note: whilst this method is the only real option, it does produce  an effect more akin to viewing the original background through haze, or fog. Applying multiple  blurs over time (each stronger than the previous) can produce a much more natural effect.

According to the documentation, it looks like none of the blur filters support time based expression.
We may get the effect of increasing blur power as the video plays, by blending the blurred video with the original video.
The weight of the original video is 1 at the beginning, and 0 at the end, and the weight of the blurred video is 0 at the beginning and 1 at the end.
Example (assume the duration of the video is 10 seconds):
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]smartblur=luma_radius=5[blr];[0:v][blr]blend=all_expr=(1-T/10)*A+(T/10)*B" output.mp4


[0:v]smartblur=luma_radius=5[blr] - blurs the input and store the result in [blr].
(1-T/10) - equals 1 when T=0 and 0 when T=10
(T/10) - equals 0 when T=0 and 1 when T=10
[0:v][blr]blend=all_expr=(1-T/10)*A+(T/10)*B applies weighted sum (blending) of the original video and the blurred video, with the blurred weight increased over time.


Example (using synthetic video):
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -filter_complex "[0:v]smartblur=luma_radius=5[blr];[0:v][blr]blend=all_expr=(1-T/10)*A+(T/10)*B" output.mp4

